# l@addto@macro undefined

Tags: errors, undefined

Do I need a special package to use `l@addto@macro`? In the MWE below, `g@addto@macro` works, but `l@addto@macro` gives an "Undefined control sequence" error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define Foo
    
        \providecommand\foo{ABC}
    
    % Append to Foo
    
        \makeatletter
        \l@addto@macro\foo{DEF} % g@addto@macro works
        \makeatother
    
    % Call Foo
    
        \foo
    
\end{document}
```

My expectation is that g@ will apply with global scope whereas l@ will apply with local scope, and I have a more complicated problem which requires a local change only.

Comment: Can you provide more context around the scope? There may be a simple alternative (copy the original command, apply the `g`lobal change, then copy back the original command).

Comment: I am using the subfiles package and I want `foo` to be defined with local scope for each subfile, then forgotten when the subfile ends so that the same macro name can be re-used (starting from a blank slate) in the next subfile.

Comment: the `g@` version is global but the `l@` one is, as you say, undefined it was just a choice of name not some general scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy the definition of the `g@` version with local rather than global definitions, but the latex format already has various versions of this in the L3 layer, here you want `\tl_put_right:Nn`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define Foo
    
        \providecommand\foo{ABC}
    
    % Append to Foo
    
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \tl_put_right:Nn\foo{DEF} % g@addto@macro works
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    
    % Call Foo
    
        \foo
    
\end{document}
```